# Endless ViewPager - Get more items from server in FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an image gallery , and I followed the sample from http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html#viewpager

I receive photos from api and if I get to the end I would like to add more .

```
   private class ImagePagerAdapter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private  int mSize;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm, int size) {
        super(fm);
        mSize = size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSize;
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position ==mSize -1)
        {
            new GetMorePhotos().execute();
        }
        else
        return ImageDetailsFragment.newInstance(photos.get(position));
    }
}
```

and in my task in post execute I added

```
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I think that the problem is that i execute the task in getItem method - here i should receive result from my task . What s the correct way to implement it ?

Comment: did you increase the `mSize` as well ?

Comment: yes      mAdapter.setSize(photos.size());
   mAdapter.setData(photos);
      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: you should post the `setSize()`, `setData()`, and `photos`, even more code.